# My web application running slowly when I was using Selenium automation tool

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I tested manually, my web application is working well, it is running very fast also. But when I was using Selenium automation tool it's taking too much time to load URL and also it's taking too much time for every action after login.

Please help me..

Comment: Is the website which you are currently working on public ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Reuse existing profile when creating driver to speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

While Execution please keep below things in mind:

1) Replace Implicit wait with Explicit Wait.
2) Reuse Browser Instance.
3) Use of Locator by following sequence:
   a) Using id is fastest one.
   b) name
   c) css selector
   d) xpath - It's better to use Relative xpath rather than Absolute xpath